# Is it possible for a human to get a disease from a feral cat?

Tags: cats

I posted a [question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/is-it-normal-for-a-feral-cat-to-let-me-pet-him-her) about a cat in our house yard. Every morning at 7am, I feed her. Is it possible for a human to get a disease from a cat? I wash my hands everytime after petting her.

Also, Is it risky for me to give her a bath? Now she don't mind closing the door and setting inside my house. By the way, she is very funny, [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/BQcsDMBB36l/?taken-by=shadeed9) is a video of her playing :D

Comment: It is definitely risky to give a cat a bath -- risky to you. Except in extreme cases, cats do not need baths; except in exceptional cases they are likely to violently protest the attempt. Unless you want to terrify the poor beast, or it is an absolute necessity, ***do not*** attempt to bathe a cat. Brushing/combing, and sometimes trimming out a knot that refuses to release any other way, are more appropriate.

Comment: Baths are risky for you, but they are also not great for the cat... Dogs f.e. don't groom themselves, so we bathe them soemtimes. But cats' fur relies on their own grooming so bathing them makes it go dry (and the skin underneath as well). 
Only exception are cats without, well, fur, because they get oily otherwise... so those have to be bathed with special soap. 

Just feeding her shouldn't give you a disease - you can get certain eye infections if you do the whole 'touch their eye then yours' thing and of course wash your hands if you touch feces.